Teukolsky's identity for Petrov type D spacetimes
I've been trying to derive the identity (2.11) from this Teukolsky paper, which reads:
$$
[D-(p+1)\epsilon + \epsilon^* + q \rho - \rho^*](\delta - p \beta + q \tau) - [\delta - (p+1)\beta - \alpha^* + \pi^* + q \tau](D - p\epsilon + q \rho) = 0
$$
where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and this should be valid for any Petrov type D spacetime.
According to Teukolsky, this identity should follow from the following Newman-Penrose equations:
$$
\begin{gather}
\delta D - D \delta = (\alpha^* + \beta - \pi^*)D  + \kappa \Delta - \sigma \delta^* - (\rho^* + \epsilon - \epsilon^*)\delta \\
D \tau - \Delta \kappa = (\tau + \pi^*) \rho + (\tau^* + \pi)\sigma + (\epsilon - \epsilon^*) \tau - (3 \gamma + \gamma^*) \kappa + \Psi_1 + \Phi_{01} \\
D \beta - \delta \epsilon = (\alpha + \pi) \sigma + (\rho^* - \epsilon^*) \beta - (\mu + \gamma) \kappa - (\alpha^* - \pi^*) \epsilon + \Psi_1 \\
 \delta \rho - \delta^* \sigma = \rho (\alpha^* + \beta) - \sigma (3\alpha - \beta^*) + (\rho - \rho^*) \tau + (\mu - \mu^*) \kappa - \Psi_1 + \Phi_{01} 
\end{gather}
$$
I tried to prove this identity by realizing that each NP equation contained one term inside each parenthesis of the identity I wanted to prove. Hence, I completed the terms that were "missing" on each of the NP equations by summing on both sides and adding the equations with the proper sign and hoped for the RHS to vanish since my LHS would be exactly the identity that is written in Teukolsky paper and numerous other papers that comment about the derivation of Teukolsky equations (for instance this one). But the RHS did not vanish, and I ended up with the following expression:
$$
[D-(p+1)\epsilon + \epsilon^* + q \rho - \rho^*](\delta - p \beta + q \tau) - [\delta - (p+1)\beta - \alpha^* + \pi^* + q \tau](D - p\epsilon + q \rho) = p(\beta D - \epsilon \delta) + q(\rho \delta - \tau D)
$$
I've redone this calculation several times, so I'm quite sure this is not some simple algebra mistake (at least, I hope so).
Since this identity should be valid for all $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$, I'm guessing that to finally prove the desired identity, I only need to show that
$$
\begin{gather}
\beta D - \epsilon \delta = 0 \\
\rho \delta - \tau D = 0 
\end{gather}
$$
But I cannot find a way to do this.
So my question is: How do I take this final step to prove this identity, or is there a simpler way to prove it?
